# op amp input biasing question: why wouldn't an input sensor draw current and get fried?

Tags: operational-amplifier, sensor, biasing

First post here, thank you in advance for all responses!

In a nutshell, my question is, if you bias the input of an op amp, why doesn't current then flow from your biasing mechanism into whatever input device's voltage you are measuring?

I am an amateur considering using an op amp voltage follower to observe from within the vehicle the output of my vehicle's ABS sensors, which I must do without affecting their voltages. I have observed them with a scope to produce 0-2ish volt low frequency sine waves.

I watched this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MtccB9K09ck&t=306s where this guy uses a variable power supply to bias his input (schematic at 6:45) and also discusses using a resistor divider (schematic at 1:54). In either case I don't see why current can't flow out to the left and start loading up my input sensor (unless I don't reference it to ground?)

Thank you very much for taking the time to try clarifying this for me!

Comment: Can you make this a standalone question, so that nobody is required to play a video to understand what you are asking?

Comment: Think about it, if you bias the opamp's inputs, then connect the sensor and current flows. Would that not **disrupt the biasing**? Note that not all sensors have a low-impedance to even make current flow. Some sensors need a biasing current themselves. TLDR: it depends on the sensor how you use it together with an opamp in a circuit configuration. I suggest that you look at and study some **practical examples** to learn how it is done. Then you can avoid wasting time on asking yourself what you're asking here.

Comment: Also, have you the free Ebook read Opamps for everyone? Find it here: https://web.mit.edu/6.101/www/reference/op_amps_everyone.pdf